# Function is not completely executed

Tags: javascript

I have this function that causes the other functions to be skipped
I was just wondering what's wrong?

```
function sToLeftDiagonal(){
    alert("sToLeftDiagonal");
    var x, y;
    var dCtr = 0;
    var hLoop = varInit.maxRow;
    for(var fifteen = 0; fifteen <= 3; fifteen++){
        x = 0;
        y = 5 - fifteen;
        for(var xy = 0; xy <= hLoop ; xy++){
            if (board[y][x] == player){
                alert("plus");
                dCtr++;
            }else{
                alert("negative");
                dCtr = 0;
            }
            if (dCtr == varInit.cWins) {
                dWinner(player);
            }
            x++;
            y--;
        }
        hLoop--;
    }

    alert("end diagonal");

}
```

I've placed a lot of 'alert' to check whether they are executed or not, apparently

```
alert("end diagonal");
```

is not executed thus skips the next function in the main program
i know this is simple, i think i'm just overlooking some things..

thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is `hLoop`'s value?

Comment: Debug with `console.log()` not with `alert()`

Comment: i don't get any errors, it simply skip some line of codes..

Comment: @user2481924 which lines are skipped

Comment: @user2481924 You're wrong, make a fiddle.  so that we can correct your mistake.

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's console log? If you use chrome there is even a debugger built in where you can step or set breakpoints...

Comment: `fifteen <= 3`?! That is quite a bad variable name!

Comment: have to checked the **dWinner** function?

Comment: There's a lot of code missing from this example.  varInit is an object with various properties.  We need to know that.

Comment: @ArunPJohny it skips the last line of the function 'alert'

Comment: My money is on varInit not existing.

Comment: Add liberally --- try { some code; } catch(e){ console.log(e); } ---- This isn't just for debugging, you should have error handling anyway. When error handling means something other than ignoring the error but printing it in the console log you can change the catch statements.

Comment: @user1671639 the whole code is a bunch, and it might missed the point of the bug

Comment: @Andbdrew this is just a prototype, sorry about that, i'll change it then

Comment: @skparwal dWinner function executes well so i'm sure that this function is the one making the fault

Comment: I'm 100% sure this is throwing an error and that's the reason you're not reaching the last `alert()`, how about you try to make a jsfiddle and let us have a look at it.

Comment: @JoeFrambach oh, that it exists..

Comment: What is the value of varInit then?

Comment: @JoeFrambach 
var varInit = {
 stat : 0,
 maxCol : 7,
 maxRow : 6,
 cWins : 4
};

Comment: Perhaps board[y][x] fails for a y such that board[y] is undefined.

Comment: Yes, before you do `if (board[y][x] == player){`, please make sure that `board[y]` actually exists.

Comment: i properly declared the 2d array with 0s as their values in a function that executes before this one.
i figured out what was causing the function to stop unexpectedly and not reach the last alert. it's because the values of [y] and [x] are wrong as i tried alerting every array index that the function goes through and there was -2 which wasn't suppose to be  there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out what was causing the function to stop unexpectedly and not reach the last alert. it's because the values of [y] and [x] are wrong as i tried alerting every array index that the function goes through and variable y had an index of [-2] which wasn't suppose to be there.